# How to circumvent error Message 241 (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am simply trying to sort by my acquisition date column that has dates in this type of format: `'04/02/2019'` etc...  I have created and column named `ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED` in an new table and I usual get the results such as: `2019-04-02`. Instead I am getting the

> error Message 241 (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string)

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT [ITEM], [ACQ_DATE],

CONVERT(DATE,[ACQ_DATE]) AS ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED
,'    ' AS MFG
INTO [ABC].[dbo].[My_Store_records_CONVERTED]
FROM [ABC].[dbo].[My_Store_records]
```

After my results I then order by `ACQ_Date_Converted`.

```
SELECT [ITEM], [ACQ_DATE]
FROM [ABC].[dbo].[My_Store_records_CONVERTED]
ORDER by [ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED]
```

My expected results should look something like this in the table:

```
       Column_A    Column_B       ColumnC
Rows   ITEM        ACQ_DATE       ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED
1.     ITEM_1      04/09/2007     2007-04-09
2.     Store item  01/26/2008     2008-01-26
etc...
```

Comment: Please tag tag the question with your RDBMS and do you know which row(s) fails?

Comment: Hi Joakim, Here is the exact message:  Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I meant what row in the database

Comment: I'm sorry, all of the rows fail.  Also, can you tell me what is RDBMS so that I can tag in my question. (I'm sorry, I'm a green newbie.)

Comment: What database are you using? That is what I am asking

Comment: Oracle Database, also using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio only works with SQL Server, not with Oracle. And the SQL in your question is invalid for Oracle to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the following query:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ACQ_DATE], 111), '/', '-') AS ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED
```

Since you are converting from `ACQ_DATE`, so you can use `ORDER BY [ACQ_DATE]`, it will work.

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=877799144214f0ba2122bcfaa361c4a0)

Comment: Almost solved my issue; I need to ORDER by [ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED] oldest to most recent.

Comment: @Dexter Please find the updated answer with the same demo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone that helped with input for this issue.

I discovered that I had a hidden character in all of the cells for the column I wanted to ORDER by; therefore, causing every line to fail.  However, with the below I was able to overcome this stumbling block.  I hope that anyone having this issue will find my solution below helpful.

**REMOVING THE HIDDEN CHARACTER.**

```
, REPLACE([ACQ_DATE], CHAR(10),'') AS [ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED]
,'    ' AS MFG
INTO [ABC].[dbo].[My_Store_records_CONVERTED]
FROM [ABC].[dbo].[My_Store_records]
```

and sorting the new table by ACQ_DATE_Converted;

```
ALTER TABLE [ABC].[dbo].[My_Store_records_CONVERTED] ALTER COLUMN [ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED] DATE NULL;
```

and then of course;

```
ORDER by [ACQ_DATE_CONVERTED]
```

Best Regards,
Dex